# What is the difference between the two types of inheritance?

Tags: javascript, oop

Tell the difference between the two types of inheritance?

```
function inherit(c,p){
    var F =function(){}
    F.prototype=p.prototype;
    c.prototype=new F();
}
```

AND

```
function inherit(c,p){
    c.prototype=p.prototype;
}
```

What are the pros and cons of each if there are such?

Comment: The first one is longer.

Comment: Second one is not an inheritance.. it can create mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second one, both `c` and `p` end up using the *same* object as their `prototype` property. So adding something to that object affects instances created with both `new c` and `new p`, because those instances get their underlying prototype from that `prototype` property on the function. That's a problem, the child shouldn't affect instances of the parent like that.

So for example, using the second one, we have this problem:

```
function Parent() {
}
function Child() {
}
inherit(Child, Parent);
Parent.prototype.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
Child.prototype.answer = 42;
var par = new Parent();
var ch = new Child();
console.log(par.question); // "Life, the Universe, and Everything"
console.log(ch.question);  // "Life, the Universe, and Everything"
console.log(par.answer);   // 42 <=== WRONG, Parent instances don't have the property
console.log(ch.answer);    // 42
```

The code above creates this situation in memory (let's use a property called `__proto__` to represent an object's underlying prototype; that's what the upcoming ES6 spec does):

```
                        The second one: Wrong
+-----------------+
| Function Parent |
+-----------------+          +---------------+
| prototype       |----+++-->| Object        |
+-----------------+    |||   +---------------+
                       |||   | question: ... |
+------------+         |||   | answer: 42    |
| Parent par |         |||   +---------------+ 
+------------+         |||
| __proto__  |---------+||
+------------+          ||
                        ||
+-----------------+     ||
| Function Child  |     ||
+-----------------+     ||
| prototype       |-----+|
+-----------------+      |
                         |
+-----------+            |
| Child ch  |            |
+-----------+            |
| __proto__ |------------+
+-----------+
```

With the *first* one, the `c.prototype` is a new object that has `p.prototype` as its underlying prototype. Adding things to `c.prototype` *won't* affect instances created with `new p`, just ones created with `new c`. But adding things to `p.prototype` affects both, which makes sense if `c` is meant to inherit from `p`.

```
function Parent() {
}
function Child() {
}
inherit(Child, Parent);
Parent.prototype.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
Child.prototype.answer = 42;
var par = new Parent();
var ch = new Child();
console.log(par.question); // "Life, the Universe, and Everything"
console.log(ch.question);  // "Life, the Universe, and Everything"
console.log(par.answer);   // undefined, Parent instances don't have the property
console.log(ch.answer);    // 42
```

That sets this up in memory:

```
                            The first one
+-----------------+
| Function Parent |
+-----------------+          +---------------+
| prototype       |----+---->| Object        |<-+
+-----------------+    |     +---------------+  |
                       |     | question: ... |  |
+------------+         |     +---------------+  |
| Parent par |         |                        |
+------------+         |                        |
| __proto__  |---------+                        |
+------------+                                  |
                                                |
+-----------------+                             |
| Function Child  |                             |
+-----------------+          +---------------+  |
| prototype       |------+-->| Object        |  |
+-----------------+      |   +---------------+  |
                         |   | __proto__     |--+
+-----------+            |   | answer: 42    |
| Child ch  |            |   +---------------+
+-----------+            |
| __proto__ |------------+
+-----------+
```

> What are the pros and cons of each if there are such?

The second one is effectively wrong. :-)

---

Side note: In an ES5-enabled environment, the first one can be simpler:

```
function inherit(c,p){
    c.prototype = Object.create(p.prototype);
}
```

---

Side note 2: To be more thorough, the first one should look like this:

```
function inherit(c,p){
    var F =function(){}
    F.prototype=p.prototype;
    c.prototype=new F();
    c.prototype.constructor = c;
}
```

or this:

```
function inherit(c,p){
    c.prototype = Object.create(p.prototype);
    c.prototype.constructor = c;
}
```

The `constructor` property of the object referenced from a `Function` object's `prototype` property should point to the function. This is how functions are set up in the specification, although it doesn't actually then *use* the `constructor` property for anything. Some people may have code that uses it, though, and expects the spec's setup to be there.

Comment: can be the minimum practical example?